# Get values from different tables into my TYPO3 extension repository

Tags: sql, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I am developing an extension with TYPO3 7.6. My extension depends on three other extensions for which there is no model or repository. I would like to use repository methods to get the query values into my extension.
  Can anyone help me with the way of writing the repository methods for fetching values from different database tables into my extension.
 Is there any good documentation for the same??
 Thank you in advance......

Comment: You can map arbitrary tables to models that you built, but have to configure it in your TypoScript setup. Here is [some documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/4-use-foreign-data-sources.html) on how to do it. So you can just build you on models and repositories for the other tables.

Comment: Thank you Jost for your comment.

Comment: Thank you jost for your comment. But I am not clear about the last line of building models and repositories. If you don't mind, Can you please explain me that??

Comment: Extbase models and repositories are classes that interact with the database. Models contain the data that was loaded from the database, or should be stored, and repositories are the classes which are used for querying (SELECT, as well as INSERT and UPDATE, ...) the database. Read a bit more in the book I linked, it's explained there.

Comment: Ok Jost. Sorry to disturb you again.. Can I simply make models and repositories into the three extensions. These extensions were in pibase and only compatability is fixed.

Comment: You should probably put them into your own extension, so you can update the other extension if necessary. But be aware that updates to those other extension could break your code, if they change the database structure or use some field differently after the update.

Comment: Can I create a class file for a pibase extension as Classes/Class.x.php? can we create namespace for this class by ourselves?  My task is to call this class  inside a extbase extension. Is this possible? If possible, how?

Comment: Yes you can create the models there as well, including a namespace. The vendor is up to you.

Answer (score -3):

It's very much worth to invest in a book such as https://amzn.com/1530534178 It covers most thing you want to do with extbase.
You can create models in your own extension for other tables. You can map the model name to the actual table name and you can map properties from the model to the actual database fields. (see also https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/b-ExtbaseReference/Index.html#persistence )
Then you need to create repository classes for these models. If you only use simple searches (`findAll` and `find(One)By<property>`) then your repository will be rather empty. Now you can link to these objects in your own models.